# Howto add Canonical Tag to the HTTP Headers for dynamically generated PDF

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website there are articles, which can be reached by URLs like `https://www.example.com/path/to/topic/`. If you append a `pdf-download/`, you will get the article as PDF.

Now I would like to dynamically add a Canonical Tag to the HTTP Headers for generated PDF files by using the `.htaccess`.

I found the following solution, which is not working for me:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/pdf-download/$ – [E=FILENAME:$1]
<FilesMatch "/pdf-download/$">
    Header add Link "< https://www.example.com/path/to/topic/%{FILENAME}e >; rel=\"canonical\""
</FilesMatch>
```

I would like to have the full domain and path to be dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<FilesMatch>` directive matches real files only, not URL-paths. The use of the `RewriteRule` directive to set an environment variable avoids the need for a `<FilesMatch>` wrapper since the `Header` directive can be set conditionally based on whether the env var is set or not.

However, an additional complication is that I suspect you also have a mod_rewrite front-controller pattern that routes these requests? In which case, the env var that is set on the first pass (eg. `FILENAME`) is renamed by prefixing with `REDIRECT_` before the next round of processing (eg. `REDIRECT_FILENAME`). So, it's this renamed env var you need to check for in the `Header` directive.

You can use the `SetEnvIf` directive instead of `RewriteRule` to set the env var, which is arguably a little simpler (and reduces the dependency on mod_rewrite).

Note that in your example, the `FILENAME` env var would contain the full URL-path (eg. `path/to/topic`) - so this shouldn't be included in the `Header` directive, as you have in your example.

Try the following instead:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(.+/)pdf-download/$" PDF_CANONICAL_URL=$1
Header add Link "<https://%{HTTP_HOST}e%{REDIRECT_PDF_CANONICAL_URL}e>; rel=\"canonical\"" env=REDIRECT_PDF_CANONICAL_URL
```

The `SetEnvIf` directive sets the `PDF_CANONICAL_URL` env var to the entire URL-path *before* `pdf-download/`. This env var contains both the slash prefix and suffix on the URL-path (as in your example URL). I changed the var name to better reflect the data being stored.

The `Header` directive sets the appropriate HTTP response header only if the `REDIRECT_PDF_CANONICAL_URL` env var is set. As noted above, this env var is set on the *second round* of rewrite processing.

However, if you are not using mod_rewrite to route these requests and instead are using `FallbackResource` (and no other mod_rewrite directives), then you will likely need to remove the `REDIRECT_` prefix. (Since there would be no second pass by the rewrite engine.)

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable is used to get the value of the requested `Host` header (domain that is requested). This assumes you are already canonicalising the hostname (ie. www vs non-www) earlier in your config.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! You made my day!